# Catch clicks on WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

My App has a page that contains a WebView with some input fields that the user has to fill. I want to catch the user click on the WebView so I can scroll it up and make sure it's completely visible. How can I catch a click event on the Webview (anywhere, it doesn't matter) yet have the events bubble to the WebView so the user can interact with the fields inside the Webview?